# How to print something out from a normal Java class in a running activity?

Tags: java, android

I am currently programming a card game with Android Studio.

The game is displayed at `MultiplayerActivity`. But the game's logic is in the normal class game.

How may I in case of an event that happens in the normal game class,print out something in the `MultiplayerActivity`? (by e.g. giving a toast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, to access your `MultiplayerActivity` from `Game.class` all you need is to pass `MultiplayerActivity` instance pointer to `Game.class` when `MultiplayerActivity` is created. There are several ways to do it:

1. Create instance of `Game.class` in `.onCreate()` method of `MultiplayerActivity` and pass `MultiplayerActivity`'s pointer (this) to `Game.class` constructor as a parameter.
2. Declare public static pointer of `MultiplayerActivity` type in `Game.class` and set `MultiplayerActivity`'s pointer (this) as value in `onCreate()` method of `MultiplayerActivity` directly (not safe) or through static setter method.
3. Or vice versa: save `MultiplayerActivity`'s pointer in `onCreate()` method in `static` variable and provide `public static` getter method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parent class and then inherit that class with all your other classes and show the toast from anywhere.

```
class ParentClass extends Activity{
   public void showToast(){}
}

class NormalPlayer extends ParentClass{
  // call methods of parent class.
}

class Multiplayer extends ParentClass{
   // call methods of parent class.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public class and then call it from another class like this:

Public class

```
public class Constants
{
  
   public static final String USERTYPE = "user_type";
    public static final String FULLNAME = "fullname";
    public static final String DOB = "dob";
    public static final String GENDER = "gender";
}
```

Access in another class like this:

```
sp.edit().putString(**ConstantSP.FULLNAME**,list.getDevProject_ProjectId()).commit();
```

Comment: Ok I don't understand that. Can I make an Example? I have the Class MultiplayerActivity this is the Activity with the xml and the Playercards and etc. Than I have the normal Java Class called Game. How can I make an Toast or an other Print Out from the Class Game? Sorry but I don't understand it from your Example.